# iOS Simulator screen recording with a Touch Indicator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Is there any way to record the iOS Simulator Screen with a **Touch Indicator** using `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo --codec=h264 --force ~/Desktop/Record.mp4`?

Note: I’ve tried with `defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ShowSingleTouches 1`
but the **Touch Indicator** doesn't include in the recorded video.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. You might need to use a library like [this](https://github.com/KaneCheshire/ShowTime) one

Comment: @aheze great library, it allows Xcode to be used and it's just adding a package to Swift

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to do it using `xcrun`. **But we can screen record in iOS simulator with a Touch Indicator with another tool**. It's not built-in in the Xcode, but it's free, easy, and available in macOS.

1. Show the touch indicators

You can use `defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ShowSingleTouches 1`, or go to "Simulator Settings" -> "Visual indicators" -> Check the "Show single touches".

[image: 1-simulator-settings]

2. Download and install OBS

Open Broadcaster Software (OBS) Studio is free, open source, and popular app for screen recording. Please visit the site to download it https://obsproject.com

3. Configure OBS

In the input source, choose "Window Capture" method, and select "[Simulator] iPhone xx" as the window.

[image: 2-screen-capture]

4. Start Recording

That's it.

[image: 3-start-recording]

I found that the file output quality is good, and the file size is small to be shared with other teams.

Answer (score 4):

You can record with the screen recorder built into the macOS (the one that's launched with Cmd+Shift+5). It records touch indicators along with the simulator's screen.